# How do I build a custom nginx:alpine based container listening on port other than 80?

Tags: docker, http, nginx, containers, alpine-linux

I need a nginx:alpine based Docker container serving http content from port 8080, but nginx:alpine listens on port 80 by default.
How can I change the port when building my custom container?

Answer (score 12):

**OPTION 1 (recommended): setting a new configuration file**

Create a local *default.conf** file with the following content:

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

** beyond port 8080, customize the above content to fit your needs*

Copy *default.conf* to the custom container [Dockerfile]:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
## Copy a new configuration file setting listen port to 8080
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**OPTION 2: changing nginx default configuration [Dockerfile]**

```
FROM nginx:alpine
## Make a copy of default configuration file and change listen port to 8080
RUN cp /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.orig && \
    sed -i 's/listen[[:space:]]*80;/listen 8080;/g' /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

*making a backup of the original config is optional, of course*

Comment: Still, nginx is exposing its port 80 and not port its port 8080 so you did half of the job here. And really, if you are going to change the config, then have your own config file with your own sensible config, rather than sed'ing in a default file and making your image heavier with a copy of it.

Comment: Thank you, @b.enoit.be. Just edited the answer to reflect your warning. Unfortunately port 80 will still be exposed, as it's inherited from nginx, but at least it will not be active in the http server, and hopefully neither published by the host machine.